# ttk Treeview, get item's bbox after scrolling into view

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on an editable `tkinter.ttk.Treeview` subclass. For editing I need to place the edit widget on top of a choosen "cell" (list row/column). To get the proper coordinates, there is the `Treeview.bbox()` method.

If the row to be edited is not in view (collapsed or scrolled away), I cannot get its `bbox` obviously. Per the docs, the `see()` method is meant to bring an item into view in such a case.

Example Code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = Tk()
tv = Treeview(root)
tv.pack()
iids = [tv.insert("", "end", text=f"item {n}") for n in range(20)]

# can only get bbox once everything is on screen.
n = [0]
def show_bbox():
    n[0] += 1
    iid = iids[n[0]]
    b = tv.bbox(iid)
    if not b:
        # If not visible, scroll into view and try again
        tv.see(iid)
        # ... but this still doesn't return a valid bbox!?
        b = tv.bbox(iid)
    print(f"bbox of item {n}", b)

btn = Button(root, text="bbox", command=show_bbox)
btn.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

(start, then click the button until you reach an invisible item)

The second `tv.bbox()` call ought to return a valid bbox, but still returns empty string. Apparently `see` doesnt work immediately, but enqeues the viewport change into the event queue somehow. So my code cannot just proceed synchronously as it seems.

How to solve this? Can `see()` be made to work immediately? If not, is there another workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even after calling `see`, the item isn't visible (and thus, doesn't have a bounding box) until it is literally drawn on the screen.

A simple solution is to call `tv.update_idletasks()` immediately after calling `tv.see()`, which should cause the display to refresh.

Another solution is to use `tv.after` to schedule the display of the box (or the overlaying of an entry widget) to happen after `mainloop` has a chance to refresh the window.

```
def print_bbox(iid):
    bbox = tv.bbox(iid)
    print(f"bbox of item {iid}", bbox)

def show_bbox():
    n[0] += 1
    iid = iids[n[0]]
    tv.see(iid)
    tv.after_idle(print_bbox, iid)
```

Comment: ``update_idletasks`` does the trick - why didn't I know about that before?! Thank you.